# Bash use of less to check in bash_aliases spools off top of terminal screen

Tags: bash, terminal, less

I use the following function to quickly review items in my bash_aliases

```
showa () { /usr/bin/grep --color=always -i -a1 $@ ~/.bash_aliases | grep -v '^\s*$' | less -FSRXc~ ; }
```

It works well except that for less than a pageful of matches,  the first two matches spool off the top of the Terminal screen, leaving the final match as the first visible line,  so I have to scroll up to see them every time. Which is a mild nuisance.   It doesn't seem to do it when there are more than a full page of matches.

Ideally I want the first match to be at the top of the screen, not shoot off it.

Adding a pipe through more is not helpful,  nor any seeming combination of alternative switches eg -j on the less command.   The terminal is standard 40 rows and no changes to Terminal settings appear to help either.

What might be a working solution? - grateful for help.

Comment: What are all those options (-FSRXc~) for?

Comment: @oguzismail pretty much as summarised in the man page.  eg the ~ removes the ~ character from empty lines at the end which otherwise are displayed.  Removing any/all the switch options still gives the same problem.  I was wondering if I was missing some obscure grep thing that less was then picking up.

Comment: @RichardL : When you do just a `less -FSRXc~ ~/.bash_aliases` (or any other file larger than your terminal height), are you also placed at the end of the file?

Comment: @RichardL : And what happens if you additionally pass the opion `-j1` to less? This should force less to jump to the first line, as if you would manually enter a _g_ command.

Comment: @user1934428    On files greater than full page it's fine.   Its for ones less than full page there is the problem.   -j1 does not help sadly.

Comment: @RichardL : But you are passing the `-F` option. This means that less should quit immediately, if there is less than a full screen to display. So this is what we should focus on. Are some lines longer than the screen width? You use `-S`, but still this is something I would test (with a short file having short lines). Finally, did you verify that your screen width and height are correctly set, and reflect the real size of the screen?

Comment: @user1934428  taking out -F or -S or any of the others do not make a diffference.   The lines are all short eg ```alias xrar='/usr/bin/nice rar a -hp -df -m5 -ep1 -rr -rv '
alias zrar='/usr/bin/nice rar a  -df -m5 -ep1 -rr -rv '
alias yrar='/usr/bin/nice rar a  -m5 -ep1 -rr -rv '
```     and the screen width and height are correct.   Tried with maximised terminal and normal.   No other screen/terminal output seems to behave incorrectly.

Comment: @RichardL : That's the point:  It is wise to keep this option, so taking them out does not tell us anything. Did you try the command outside the pipe, i.e. sending the stdout of `grep -v` to a temporary file, and then invoking `less` on this file manually? Do you still see this odd behaviour?

Comment: @RichardL : What I would definitely remove from the options, is `-R`, at least while debugging this issue,  but I would add `-nLU`, just for the safe side, so the options should be `-FSXcnLU`.

Comment: @RichardL : And remove the `--color=always`, at least while researching the problem.

Comment: @RichardL : Just experimented a bit with less. `-c` also could counteract the effect of -F, so please try it with the options `-FSXnLU`.

Comment: @user1934428   taking out the c option didn't help.     Perversely,  taking out the pipe into less completely does give a useable solution for less than a screenful.  Piping into more rather than into less  still gives the same problem.   I wonder if there is a kludge solution to insert in three blank lines before the pipe into less,  although how to do it I don't know.

Comment: @RichardL : Rather than trying a hack, better investigate this problem further. Did you remove the colouring, as I recommended? Did you experiment with different files in input? I would start it slowly, first with an unnecessary `cat`, just to have a pipe: `cat SOMEFILE|less`. If this looks reasonable, then introduce successively  `grep` commands as you have in your solution, one after the other, until you arrive finally to your current pipe. And one stage, the weird behaviour must be introduced.

Comment: @user1934428  yes taking out colouring did not help.   I would like to know if others have seen the same behaviour or if it is local to me.  Straightforward cat FILE | less is working fine.  I will continue investigating.

Comment: @RichardL : I tried to replicate it, but it worked as documented. So I would really do the debugging step by step, as you suggested. In addition, I suggest that you also add a link to a screenshot of that problem to your question. While screenshots are generally discouraged in SO, this is an example where a screenshot might help, in particular because you said that removing the `-c` option does not change anything, which is **really** odd. Please also make sure that you don't have an environment variable named `LESS` defined, as it could ruin our debugging attempts.

Comment: @RichardL : Besides the environment variable `LESS`, make also sure that you don't have a _lesskey file_ which interferes (i.e. check that  `ls $HOME/.less` does not show any file, and that the environment variable `LESSKEY` does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

Located the issue.  There was a spurious "1" on the `-a` switch.

This is the final solution,  presenting also a few lines context ahead of the match.

```
showa () { /usr/bin/grep -B 5 --color=always -i -a $@ ~/.bash_aliases | grep -v '^\s*$' | less -FSRXc~ ; }
```

Comment: I've seen the `1`, but thought it was deliberate, because I mistakingly thought that `-a` and `-A` is the same, and `-A`  would **require**  a numeric argument. BTW, why are you using `-a`? The purpose of this option is, according to the man-page, to _Process a binary file as if it were text_, but `.bash_aliases` is always a text file.

Comment: @user1934428 the honest answer is that I got the bulk of it from online and missed that in my checking.   Appreciated all your help btw.